# Imaging System overwrites computer object already in use

Tags: active-directory, sccm, imaging

We are having a issues with imaging and it taking over the object in AD even if its already tie to another system. So if we image a system and use a wrong name, but that name is already in AD, it will take over that object and then the other computer will loss the trust and give a error. So if the computer needs to be, abc123, but if fat finger and type abc112, it will take over abc112 and the system that was using abc112 will loss trust. I think its a permission issue on AD group that give us access to that OU. Where its giving us access to overwrite objects without having to reset the object first. I know in AD you can reset the computer object and i thought that is what you needed to do before you can reuse the object, that isnt happening now.

Comment: That is absolutely default behavior afaik. Otherwise you would have to manually delete ad objects whenever you want to reimage an existing computer. As the behavior is only affecting you if you make an error do you really want to change how the ad handles this? I would rather propose the following: Use a small script (or program if you like that better) to create your computer records. Then you can easily check if the name exists in the ad already and prompt an error to give the user a choice of what to do next.

Comment: No it’s not just affecting me, but when anyone images a system wrong. What is the point of doing the reset computer object within ad? I thought that was the whole point on the resetting the computer object within AD? So if you have to reimaged a system you go into ad and right click the computer object and reset the secure channel so when imaging it knows that system is free to be taken over.

Comment: I'm not 100#% sure but i think it is just for when the trust fails and the computer cannot communicate anymore (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee198778(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). I think even if you took SCCMs rights to overwrite a AD object away (which you can, I just don't think it is a great idea) it would then not work after a reset. If you really want to design it that way you would have to delete all AD objects before reimagening losing all group memberships and the location (OU). Is that preferable to a check before import in your situation?